# mac pretty print json file without character escaping

Tags: python, json

Running on Mac OS.
I need to pretty print a file.json stored on my local disk to a new file file_formatted.json WITHOUT transforming any characters of the data.

I am currently using the python json.tool :

cat file.json    | python -m json.tool > file_formatted.json

which formats nicely but transforms characters, checkout the example below 
`…` is changed to `\u2026`

I checked the documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) but cannot find any usefull info, is there a way to disable the character escaping?

Original:

```
     {
     "date": "2016-06-01",
     "duration": "00:13:25"
     "subTitle": "A world first is one click away!",
     "title": "Alice in wonderland…"
     }
```

After:

```
    {
        "date": "2016-06-01",
        "duration": "00:13:25",
        "subTitle": "A world first is one click away!",
        "title": "Alice in wonderland\u2026"
    }
```

Comment: `\u2026` is not an escape character (`\\` is), it is a non-ASCII Unicode character.

Comment: @DYZ indeed you are correct, I will update my question

Answer (score 2):

To get the result you want, `json.dump()` (or `json.dumps()`) command should be called with argument `ensure_ascii=False` (the default is `True`).

Comment: Have a look to my commend on the answer of @Blender I get an error if I try to use the ensure_ascii=False

Comment: @HixField try to point Python3 instead of just Python: ```cat file.json | python3 -c "import sys,json; ...```

Answer (score 2):

Both versions of your JSON represent the exact same object:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{"foo": "…"}') == json.loads('{"foo": "\u2026"}')
True
```

If you want Python to not escape the characters in the final output, [the module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/json/tool.py) doesn't provide any command-line interface to the `ensure_ascii` flag. You could do it yourself, though:

```
$ echo '{"foo": "\u2026"}' | python -c "import sys,json; print(json.dumps(json.load(sys.stdin), indent=4, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8'))"
{
    "foo": "…"
}
```

Comment: If I use "cat file.json    | python -c "import sys,json; print(json.dumps(json.load(sys.stdin), indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))" > file_formatted.json" I get an error when executing :: "File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 9852: ordinal not in range(128)
done

Comment: @HixField: Forgot to encode the output. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
    python3 -m json.tool [path of your file] --no-ensure-ascii
```

The `--no-ensure-scii` parameter does

> Disable escaping of non-ascii characters

From the documentation of [`json.tool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json.tool)

Comment: It will be an even better answer, if you explain it.

Comment: `error: unrecognized arguments: --no-ensure-ascii` - I am using Python 3.8.10